# UV Mapping brick fireplace

Tags: texturing, uv

I wondering what is the best and quick way to texturing fireplace made from bricks.
The fastest way is to use box project, but there is some issue (on picture).
The more complicated method is to unwrap fireplace, and hand correct the UV (grab, scale etc) but it is very time-consuming. Off course i can use texture paint, but i would like to use PBR texture.
What is the best way in your opinion to texturing that fireplace?

Thanks for help,  [image]